# Adding an application icon to a freepascal/SDL program?

Tags: icons, sdl, freepascal, titlebar, application-icon

I have installed freepascal on Windows 7, but did not install an IDE.

How do I add an icon to the program I am developing? I have searched using Google, but most results point to the Lazarus IDE forums. The tips there all seem to refer to some sort of *.lpi file which I don't have.

Thanks.

[update]

I got it partially working. I can see the icon when looking at the EXE in File Explorer. But when launching the application the icon does not appear in the title bar.

[update]

The program is a video game utilizing SDL. I did some research and have gathered together the following lines of code:

```
RWop := SDL_RWFromFile('gharena.ico', 'rb');
ICOimage := IMG_Load_RW(RWop, 1);
//ICOcolorkey := SDL_MapRGBA(ICOimage^.format, 0, 0, 0, 0);
//SDL_SetColorKey(ICOimage, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, ICOcolorkey);
SDL_WM_SetIcon(ICOimage, Nil);
```

It seems to work, mostly. The icon appears in both the title bar and the taskbar. However, the title bar icon has messed up transparency. The icon is a 32-bit sprite named 'gharena.ico'. When running the game the transparent parts of the image are rendered in black in the program title bar. The taskbar icon is okay and has proper transparency.

In the code above you can see I have messed with setting the color key. But it doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that you have an icon file named **project.ico**.

Create a file named **project.rc**, with the following content:

```
ICON_1 ICON "project.ico"
```

Create a file named **buildres.cmd**, with the following content:

```
@echo off

set path=C:\FPC\3.0.0\bin\i386-win32\

windres.exe -i project.rc -o project.res

pause
```

Of course, don't forget to adapt the path to FPC bin directory according to your own installation.

Double click on **buildres.cmd**. You get a file named **project.res**.

Now, a test program:

```
program project;

{$R project.res}

begin
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: This adds an icon to the executable in File Explorer, but not to the window itself when it is active and running. So it's only a partial answer.